# swap option missing while installing in ubuntu server 14.04 lts

Tags: server, system-installation, swap

There is no option to select swap partition while installing the server version....I have tried all the possible ways to check the option and not found anything. Is their anyway to enter manually

Comment: Are you sure? I installed a server today with 14.04 LTS and during partitioning I got to set a 'swap'. This is a method to create it after installing: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: but i want to know why the swap option is missing in partition disks list.

Comment: it should be listed as a format on the list of format types you can select as linux-swap or something like that and you need available space (of course).

Answer (score 5):

mchid answered this in a comment, but just for the sake of completeness...

It's under 'Use as', not 'Mount point', switch from Ext4 to swap area.